# Handlebars: How to set template name when precompiling

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js, precompile

I have such project structure:

```
app
-views
--layouts
---landing.handlebras
---main.handlebars
--pages
--parts
```

when i try to precompile handlebars with

```
handlebars app/views > app/views/compiled.js -m
```

...the output templates have names like `'<directory>/<filename>'` i.e. `'layout/main'`, `'layout/landing'` etc. The question is how to set custom names for templates?